# My program does not run properly when compiled with icc

Tags: c, icc

I'm having a problem with icc and so far I've not found any solution. My program runs normally when compiled with gcc, but apparently does not perform any operation when compiled with icc. No runtime errors occur. The program just ends very fast (a few milliseconds), but was expected to take a few seconds (about 11 seconds for *n* = 1 billion). However it works okay if I print the total at the end.

It's a small code:

```
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>

double f(double x){
    double pi = 3.141592653589793;
    double value;
    value = 50.0 / (pi * (2500.0 * x * x + 1.0));
    return value;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    double a = 0.0, b = 10.0, total = 0.0, x;
    unsigned long int i, n = 1000000000;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        x = ((n - i - 1) * a + (i) * b) / (n - 1);
        total = total + f(x);
    }
    total = (b - a) * total / (double) n;

    //printf("%f\n", total);
    return 0;
}
```

I also checked that it actually runs the loop and calls the function *n* times.

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However it works okay if I print the total at the end.

This is probably an [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) effect (legal, per the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).

Since there is no visible [side-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) in your program (without the `printf`), the compiler is allowed (per the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule)) to optimize it into a no-operation program.

With some versions of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org), and some [optimization flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) you could observe the same. Try to compile your code with `gcc -O3 -S -fverbose-asm` and look into the generated assembler code (you'll observe an empty generated `main` with GCC 8.1 on Linux/x86-64)

> Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

Your code, and your misunderstanding of the tricky [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) of C. The implementation is behaving per the C standard (and your program is *running properly*).

BTW, even with the `printf`, in theory the compiler is allowed to optimize your program into a simple constant `printf`. In practice, current compilers are (sadly) not that clever.

If you want some robust benchmark, the `n` could depend on the program arguments (and you still need to keep the `printf`, because you want some visible side-effect) perhaps:

```
 unsigned long n = (argc<2)?1000:(unsigned long)atol(argv[1]);
```

When measuring performance, don't forget to enable optimizations in your compiler!

BTW, in a few years (after having followed more CS courses, including one on compilation, and/or having read the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)), you might try to implement some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) which would be able to optimize your function with an explicit `printf` (but still `n` being initialized to a compile-time constant) into a `main` just calling some `printf` and doing the loop computing `total` at *compile-time* (such an optimization is legal). You'll discover that making such an optimization takes a lot of work (certainly months, perhaps years!), and might [not](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273711/40065) apply to a lot of existing programs, but you could have fun implementing it.

If you are interested in floating point calculations, be sure to read the [floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) (it is tricky).

Comment: I actually removed printf because I'm trying to compare this sequential code with several other parallel versions of it (which work without printf). So I was only printing the runtime. I use n as an argument using this same syntax in the original version. But I did not realize this icc optimization issue. Thanks!

Comment: It is *not* an issue with `icc`. The issue is your misunderstanding of the C semantics and its as-if rule. As I have shown, GCC have the same ability to optimize (but you need to ask for it)

Comment: Thanks for all of this additional information. I will certainly consider implementing this plugin as part of my future research.